# _onloadHook error with Facebook Iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

On IE with an empty cache, the Facebook iframe is throwing a _onloadHook error.

To reproduce: empty the cache in IE (cookies, cache, everything)

Visit: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com (or any URL)

IE (if you have the "display every error" preference turned on) will throw this error:

```
Message: The value of the property '_onloadHook' is null or undefined, not a Function object
Line: 202
Char: 436
Code: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

We got the same error.  Remove the ".php", or remplace with .potato instead :D you'll get another completely different script from facebook that is working fine without this error, that we get also only in IE.